# jQuery file upload plugin working but files not uploading

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm using Blueimp jQuery file upload plugin for uploading image files.

I am using the default "Basic Plus" from the demo with auto upload enabled. I can see the call to `server/php/` for file upload as soon as I drop file on the drop zone. but file does not seem to be uploaded.

Here's my code:

```
<form>
  <div class="asset_upload has_file js-asset-upload project required">
    <div class="error">
      <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="success">
      <div class="image-clip">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upload">
      <input class="photo file" data-help_section="project-image-help" id="fileupload" name="project[photo]" type="file">
      <strong class="center">
        Choose an image from your computer <span class="has_file_hide">This is the main image.</span><span>JPEG, PNG, GIF</span>
      </strong>
      <div class="progress finished">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="percentage">Processing...</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'server/php/';

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        method: 'GET',
        dropZone: $('#fileupload'),
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),


    }).on('dragover', function (e) {
        var dropZone = $('.asset_upload .upload'),
            timeout = window.dropZoneTimeout;
        if (!timeout) {
            dropZone.addClass('in');
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        var found = false,
            node = e.target;
        do {
            if (node === dropZone[0]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            node = node.parentNode;
        } while (node != null);
        if (found) {
            dropZone.addClass('hover');
        } else {
            dropZone.removeClass('hover');
        }
        window.dropZoneTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.dropZoneTimeout = null;
            dropZone.removeClass('in hover');
        }, 100)
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        //Hides error
        $('.error').hide().children().text('');

    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index];

        if (file.preview) {
            // node
            //     .prepend('<br>')
            //     .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            $('.error')
                .fadeIn()
                .children()
                .text(file.error);
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            // data.context.find('button')
            //     .text('Upload')
            //     .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress').fadeIn();
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        alert(data.result.files);
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {

            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
            $('.progress').fadeOut();
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index) {
            var error = 'File upload failed.';
            $($('.error').children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
            $('.progress').fadeOut();
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});

</script>
```

As per response from `server/php` I can see `{"files":[]}` So its clear that files are not uploading.

I can see the request as `https://localhost/dropzone/server/php/index.php?[object%20FormData]&_=1478101410337` and getting `{"files":[]}` as response.

I am pretty new to this plugin any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get that response from the server? Where is your PHP-code? Have you tried dumping the `$_FILES` variable to see what you actually are getting from the front end? Do you have a `server/php` end point?

Comment: No I am using default php file from the demo itself, which is located in `server/php` path

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all or did you just rush here, hoping that we magically would know what your set up looks like?

Comment: For me, I think `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is missing in `<form>` may be one of the reason.

Comment: ...and a post method.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I am using code from the demo which I mentioned in the question! here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic-plus.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- GET is just for debugging purpose.

Comment: look at your console then and use error reporting

Comment: you've been given an "answer" below; see that

Comment: Where is your file uploading file.? I'm not able to see any where in your given code. How files will *go and sit* in your required directory structure through dropzone?

Comment: There's no error @Fred-ii-. and there's an empty response as `{"files":[]}`

Comment: @NanaPartykar as I said earlier I am using files from the demo itself to understand. The uploading file is located at `server/php` you can have a look here. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: I already looked there.

Comment: Last ditch effort: How are you using this file, as `http://localhost` (or hosted), or as `file:///`? I don't know what else to say here. If that github code is supposed to run "out of the box", then there must be something you're not doing.

Comment: I am using http://localhost and my request is going as `https://localhost/dropzone/server/php/index.php?[object%20FormData]&_=1478101410337` and getting response as `{"files":[]}`

Answer (score -2):

Just using a javascript library to upload files wont work.

You need to have code (in this case in a php file) to handle the file upload when it reaches the server. Unless you have that then just using your javascript plugin wont work.

Comment: Ofcourse there is a php file to handle the request. as I mentioned in my question that I am using demo files provided with the plugin located at `server/php` https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php